# In Minecraft, can ocelots get lost during teleports?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tamed an ocelot, and I was far away from my home so my friend teleported me to where he was.

But when I arrived, my cat didn't teleport to where I was.

Can cats die during its teleport or something?

Comment: This story is heart-wrenching.

Comment: Have you checked for [chronoton emissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Next_Phase)?

Answer (score 7):

In Minecraft, only a 9 chunk radius around a player are loaded at any given time. A chunk is a 16x16x256 area. If your friend teleported you more than 9 chunks away from where you found the ocelot, then the chunk you found it in would become unloaded, and the cat would not be able to teleport to you.

If you walk towards the last location of your cat, it should immediately teleport to you as soon as you are within 9 chunks of its coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

cats can't die during its teleport, you can just go pick them up if you teleported more than 9 chunks away like rpedroso said. What he didn't mention is don't forget to right click your cat at your home. This will help from certain glitches, also should be done when you go to the nether since the ocelot can't go there.